# How to setup global secured class php

Tags: php, class, global

I'm trying to access public method from class from function in another class
i have:

File with main functions

```
class kernel(){

private $conn;

private function mysqlconnection(){

$conn = new Mysqlconnection(); //Setup connection


}
private function makequery($query){

$this->conn->do_query($query); //do mysql query

}

public function query($query){

//check rank
...
 return $this->makequery($query); //if true do it

}

}
```

App function template file

```
Class app{

function __construct($appname){
//Check that this app can get connection (try make query)

$kernel->query($appname); 

}    

    }

$kernel = new kernel ();

$app = new app($appname); //HOW to access another class from class?
```

I made it through calling class to globals

```
$GLOBALS['kernel'] = new kernel();
```

and in app class
...

```
    Class app{

function __construct($appname){
//Check that this app can get connection (try make query)

$GLOBALS['kernel']->query($appname); 

}    

    }
```

but can i do it more safety ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject an instance of `kernal` via the constructor

```
Class app{

    protected $kernal;

    function __construct($appname, $kernal)
    {
        $this->kernal = $kernal //if needed in other methods, save to a property
        $this->kernal->query($appname); 
    }    
}


$kernel = new kernel ();

$app = new app($appname, $kernal);
```

Comment: Yes but i want to acces it from functions too and including class in every function would be problematic.

Comment: `function Test(){ $kernel->query("Some query ") }`

Comment: @MarekZgajewski By functions, do you mean other methods in the same class? Or actual procedural php functions?

Comment: I mean that i need to access to main class from everywhere, simply make it  like global.

Comment: OK, well global scope is global scope, how you achieve it makes little difference - you can stick with the GLOBALS array, or make it static, or make it a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by reference to function. 
ex

```
function ClassName(){
if(!isset($GLOBALS["ClassName"]))
$GLOBALS["ClassName"] = new $GLOBALS["ClassName"];

return $GLOBALS["ClassName"];
}
```

And you can call it by

```
ClassName()->query("...");
```

from anywhere ! :D